# First-chance exception at <addr> in <myapp>: 0x000006BA: The RPC server is unavailable

Tags: exception, sockets

What does it mean:
"First-chance exception at  in : 0x000006BA: The RPC server is unavailable"
?

this debug message appears in Debug output of visual studio debugger when I using socket connection, but I don't know what operation initiates this message...

Answer (score 5):

"First-chance exception" occurs when the exception is thrown, before anyone catches it. Usually, these are benign, and can be ignored (because someone is going to catch it).

You can get the debugger to break when the exception is thrown, whether or not someone later catches it.

In Visual Studio, this is done by choosing Debug / Exceptions and putting a check in the "Thrown" column for the exceptions you're interested in. Then, when the exception is thrown, the debugger will break at the relevant place.

Note that you might end up in the middle of nowhere (i.e. in disassembly), so make sure that you've got your debugging symbols configured correctly.

Also note that some exceptions aren't in the list by default, so you'll have to click the "Add..." button in that dialog.

Answer (score 3):

This is most likely a bug (see these threads: [1](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ar/vsdebug/thread/5b4513a4-fcb8-46d6-a6c2-618492bce016) and [2](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ar/vsdebug/thread/20c8b7c5-8e8b-4aaa-9d8d-3640c37948cc)).

I get this when debugging a C# application that calls into a COM object written in C++ when the COM object calls WNetOpenEnum (which succeeds, by the way). My system is Windows 7 x64 SP1 and fully patched, Visual Studio 2010. It happens regardless if VS is started as elevated process or normally.

Answer (score 0):

The debugger reports you likely have not enabled remote debuggimg.

Check if you have Remote Procedure Call service enabled and running (MMD.exe process). This service is required by remote debugging feature.

You may try to follow [How to turn on remote debugging](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=833977)

Comment: @CJohnson I don't have any updated link, but have you checked the answer by Helge Klein above?